# The best way to find the Department with the maximum total salary Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Lets we have 2 standard tables Employees and Departments

```
CREATE TABLE departments (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE employees (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  department_id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR,
  salary NUMERIC(13,2)
);
```

What is the best way to find the name of the department with the maximum employees' total salary.

I've found two solutions and they looks too complicated for such simple task.

**Using rank()**

```
SELECT name FROM (
   SELECT name, rank() OVER ( ORDER BY salary DESC ) AS rank
   FROM (
          SELECT
            departments.name,
            sum(salary) AS salary
          FROM employees
            JOIN departments ON department_id = departments.id
          GROUP BY departments.name
        ) AS t1
 ) AS t2
WHERE rank = 1;
```

**Using subquery**

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT
         departments.name,
         sum(salary) AS salary
       FROM employees
       JOIN departments ON departments.id = employees.department_id
       GROUP BY departments.name
)
SELECT name FROM t1
WHERE t1.salary = (SELECT max(salary) FROM t1);
```

At first glance using rank should be less efficient as it performs unnecessary sorting. Though `EXPLAIN` shows that the first option is more efficient.
Or maybe someone suggests another solution.

So, what is the best way to find the Department with the maximum total salary using postgres?

Comment: Check the execution plans generated `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Answer (score -1):

I would write the `rank()` as:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT d.name, SUM(e.salary) AS salary,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(e.salary)) as rnk
      FROM employees e JOIn
           departments d
           ON e.department_id = d.id
      GROUP BY d.name
     ) d
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

(The additional subquery should not affect performance, but it adds nothing to clarify the query either.)

Because window functions are built-in to the database, the database has methods for making them more efficient.  And there is overhead for getting the `MAX()` as well.  But, to be honest, I would expect both methods to have similar performance.

I should note that if you want only one department returned -- even when there are ties -- then the simplest method is:

```
      SELECT d.name, SUM(e.salary) AS salary
      FROM employees e JOIn
           departments d
           ON e.department_id = d.id
      GROUP BY d.name
      ORDER BY SUM(e.salary) DESC
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```